# How to conditionally change the value of observations in R when having a list of dataframes

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a list of data frames and want to apply changes to any cell in any data frame given that the condition is met.

**Example**

```
mydatalist[[1]][mydatalist[[1]] == "N"] <- NA
```

Here I replace any cell that matches "N" with NA in the first data frame, but I want this to apply to all data frames. Does anyone know of a quick way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: I'd use `lapply`. A very rudimentary example might be: `list_data <- list(d1 = mtcars, d2=mtcars);
lapply(list_data,function(x){x[x[,"cyl"]==4,]})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `data.table`:

```
my_func <- function(dataset, condition){
  require(data.table)
  setDT(dataset)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) ifelse(x == condition, NA, x))]
}

lapply(mydatalist, my_func, condition = "N")
```